# Methods for nonquadratic Hamiltonian in second quantizaion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, many-body, second-quantization

Quadratic Hamiltonian ($A, B, C$ constants)

$H_Q = A a^{\dagger} a + B a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} + C a a $

may be diagonalized by [Bogoliubov transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation).

Consider other terms

$H_{NQ} = D a^{\dagger} a a + E a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} a + F aaa + G aaaa + ...$

How other terms can be treated in total Hamiltonian $H_T = H_Q + H_{NQ}$?

EDIT: Can reccommend book that that treats nonlinear Hamiltonian in second quantization with perturbative methods?

Comment: Non-linear theories typically require perturbation theory or variational methods (the latter being very specific to each problem, with no general procedure for arbitrary Hamiltonians). Few exact solutions are known beyond these approximate methods.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thank you. Can you reccommend a book for treating nonlinear theories in perturbation theory?

Comment: @Nigel1 Virtually *any* book will do. Perturbation theory is the only tool that can be studied systematically, so all books spend thousands of pages describing how to use it.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Unfortunately I am very uneducated on  topic :-( Can you reccommend book that that treats nonlinear Hamiltonian in second quantization with perturbative methods?

Comment: I suggest you start looking at phi^4 theory, so for this one you could take Ryder Quantum Field Theory